# super of equal methods in classes with multiple inheritance

Tags: python, django

I have a class that inherits from two others and I want to get the return of the method called "render" that both have this method

ex:

```py
class A:
    def render(self, value, name):
        return 'render A'

class B:
    def render(self, value, name):
        return 'render B'

class C(B, A):
    def render(self, value, name):
        render_a = #here get the value of A
        render_b = #here get the value of B
        return render_a
```

Comment: Python follows the MRO, so super moves up the MRO order in search for render and will stop at the first match. If that match calls a super, then it will move further in the hierarchy.

Comment: MRO = method resolution order.

Comment: If you want to call *both* inherited methods, when neither one is written to call a parent method, then you have to explicitly call the methods from each class: `A.render(self, ...)` and `B.render(self, ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should here specify the classes explictily. You can take a look at the direct base classes, or look at the entire MRO, but then you will need to specify what to do if later another direct (or indirect) superclass is added. You thus can call it with `A.render(self, value, name)`:

```
class C(B, A):
    def render(self, value, name):
        render_a = A.render(self, value, name)
        render_b = B.render(self, value, name)
        return render_a
```